# Difference between os.system("pwd") and os.getcwd()

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, os.system

I have a basic doubt regarding the 3 families of functions below:

Say for example, I would like to know the current working directory in Python. So some of the ways of achieving this could be :

```
os.system("pwd")

os.getcwd()

subprocess.Popen(['pwd'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

I found many resources online differentiating the third one above with the rest, but could not find much particularly around the difference between the first 2 above.

Please help me understand the difference among the 3, especially

1. from an output point of view
2. from a performance point of view
3. from an implementation point of view, that is, how are these three internally implemented, as in, for each of these do they spawn a new process, how do they interact with the kernel etc.

Any pointers to for my self reference would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `os.getcwd()` gets the directory as a string, the others spawn the `pwd` process. Spawning a process to get the directory is silly.

Comment: okie.. could you please point me to some resources that can elaborate on this and help me understand it in depth ?

Comment: `help(os.getcwd)`, `help(os.system)`, https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

Comment: well for one [`os.getcwd`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=os.getcwd#os.getcwd) would get the current working directory **in python** where as the `pwd` **could be** executed in a subprocess with a different execution environment **or** might not be available **or** would give the path in a format that would needed to be decoded before it could be used.   I'm definitely with Alaxander on this one, spawning a process to get the working directory is silly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way of finding the performance issues is to measure it yourself.  Python implementations vary.  Equally, if you want to find out how they are implemented then read the source code.

All these mechanisms will probably call the same underlying C library interface `getcwd(3)` on UNIX-like systems.  Its just that some use an external program to get there.

`os.system("pwd")` runs a shell (1st process) to run the external program `pwd` (2nd process).  So the performance will be poor and it is not portable since `pwd` is not implemented on all platforms that support Python.  The output goes the `stdout`, it is not captured for use in the program.

You omitted the function `popen`:

```
wd = os.popen('pwd').readline()
```

This is considered obsolete, and so is `os.system()`, both being replaced by `subprocess`.  The `popen` implementation might use the C runtime-library function `popen`, which also invokes a shell to execute the command, so performance might be poor.

The `subprocess` module was meant to replace these old interfaces, hence the duplication.  One advantage is that the use of a shell is optional, and in this case you don't need it.  But your code is incomplete:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['pwd'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
wd, err = proc.communicate()
if err:
    print >> sys.stderr, err
else:
    print wd,
```

That is going to be more efficient because there is no shell process.  But really you should benchmark it yourself on your own system.

All the interfaces so far are *general* - they are for running a large variety of commands and external programs.  The fact that they are often abused and used inappropriately is a refection of the lack of understanding (or laziness) of the programmer.

We are left with `os.getcwd()`.  It is probably implemented as a direct call to the C library interface, but might circumvent that to call the kernel.  Check the source code on your implementation.  No child processes, so faster.

Your point about duplication could also be made for many other interfaces, `os.remove()`, `os.mkdir()`, `os.stat()`, and so on.  The point is that these are fast and portable, they don't run other programs.

Having these direct interfaces is a major advantage of using a language like Python compared to using a shell.  Bash has no built-in command for getting the current directory, getting a file size, deleting a file, etc.  It relies on external programs - python does not.

Comment: A small doubt with the part where you mentioned : "os.system("pwd") runs a shell (1st process) to run the external program pwd (2nd process)."
So I ran os.system("cat") and in different terminal did ps -a. I could see a new pid for cat but there wasn't any new shell process created. Am i doing something wrong here ?

Comment: @geek_ji:  Implementations might vary, but the doc says: "Execute the command (a string) in a **subshell**. This is implemented by calling the Standard C function **system()**."  The description of the C function `system()` (see `man 3 system`) specifically says "pass a command to the **shell**".  So not sure about the `ps`, maybe the shell is `exec`ing` the `cat`.  I know that later versions of `ksh` do that.  An `strace` might resolve that - sorry but I don't have time to dig that far today, I'll try to get back to it.

Comment: @geek_ji:  you have made me curious now.  I'll try to dig into this when I can, but probably not today.

Comment: that'd be nice. In fact, i would like to help with this investigation. Let me know if I can be of any help.

Comment: @geek_ji:  are you familiar with `strace`?  Something like `strace -o strace.out -f python gash.py` (where gash.py is your script).  Then look at the file strace.out (it could be large).  I'm suspicious that this is something specific to `cat`, so try with `pwd`.

Comment: sure (Y) let me try that out !

Answer (score 7):

The `os.getcwd()` call will be faster, as it doesn't rely on any external dependencies. Your first and last example both execute a separate process, the `pwd` system command, and return its output as a string. Well, your `Popen()` example will require you to get its output using another call, but I digress.

There's simply no need to call an external command; just use `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: I wonder, if at all it can be done using os.getcwd() why at all do we have a provision for the other two? Are there any specific use case where the other 2 are more useful than their os.getcwd()  counterpart ?

Comment: @geek_ji: There would indeed be very little reason to use `os.system` or `subprocess.Popen` to get the CWD. You can obviously run arbitrary commands with them, however, so they are useful for other things.

Comment: Right, `os.system()` and `process.Popen()` are used for calling arbitrary system commands. In this situation, there's no need to call any system commands.

Comment: @Will:  this might be pedantic, but I question your term "*system commands*".  `os.system()` always runs a shell, and `subprocess.Popen()` will run a shell if `shell=True`, so in those circumstances they can run *shell* commands - but only the default shell (`sh` on UNIX-like systems).  In all circumstances they can run external programs, provided the location is obtainable.

Answer (score 4):

The major difference between all three is that only one, `os.getcwd()` is guaranteed to work.

The other two rely on `pwd` which is not available in all operating systems.

As @Will mentioned in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37638769/790387), spawning a separate process for this information is unnecessary; and it may give you unexpected results.

Answer (score 2):

There is one occasionally annoying difference. The os.getcwd() function seems to use os.realpath internally, so if the directory you are in is a symlink you will get a different result than from pwd. If also means that you might get a different directory back than the one you did a os.chdir to.

```
% pwd
/tmp
% pwd -P
/ram/tmp

% python3 -c "import os ; os.chdir('/tmp') ; print(os.getcwd())"
/ram/tmp
% python2 -c "import os ; os.chdir('/tmp') ; print os.getcwd()"
/ram/tmp
```